# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value as I am trying to save an object with NSuserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to save an instance of a class in my userdefaults i have use the following method to do so and it doesn't seem to work after adding the isImportant attribute in my class.
here is my code

```
class Task: NSObject , NSCoding {
var taskDate:String
var task:String
var isImportant:Bool

init(task: String , taskDate: String , isImportant: Bool){
    self.task = task
    self.taskDate = taskDate
    self.isImportant = isImportant
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let taskDate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "taskDate") as? String ,
        let task = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "task") as? String ,
        let importantdecode = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "importantBool") as? Bool else {
            return nil
    }
    self.init(task: task, taskDate: taskDate , isImportant:importantdecode)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(taskDate, forKey: "taskDate")
    aCoder.encode(task, forKey: "task")
    aCoder.encode(isImportant, forKey: "importantBool")
}
}
```

The above code is my class i have added some protocols which honestly i don't know how they properly work clarification is appreciated ofc.

Now this is where i am facing the problem.

```
    var tasks = [Task]()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaultskey:String = "save"
    et task:Task = Task(task: taskTextField.text!, taskDate: now ,isImportant: false )


        tasks.append(task)


        // Calling the saveTask Function
        saveTasks()

        // Calling the shake function in the custombutton class since we declared the sender here to be CustomButtom
        sender.shake()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Getting the permanent Storage
        loadTasks()





    // Saving array of objects with userDefaults
    func saveTasks() {
        do {
            let taskDataWorking = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tasks, requiringSecureCoding: false) // archiving data for object to be able to store it.

            defaults.set(taskDataWorking, forKey: defaultskey)
            //throw MyError.FoundNil("xmlDict")

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }



    // Loading the data

    func loadTasks(){

        let taskData = defaults.object(forKey: defaultskey) as? NSData

        if let taskData = taskData {
            do {
                let taskArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(taskData as Data) as? [Task] // unarchiving data as and loading it
** The error occurs here **     tasks = taskArray! // assigning the tasks to the archived value when saved so when it launched we will be back at the last saved tasks
                tasksAccomplished = taskArray!.count 

            } catch {
                print("error while loading")
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you know `taskArray` is `nil` (since it crashes when you force-unwrap it), then you know that the optional cast to `[Task]` is failing (since you know that `taskData` is not `nil`). Therefore you know that the data you are getting from `UserDefaults` is not actually an array of `Task`.

Comment: Delete and reinstall your app. Perhaps there is some other data in `UserDefaults` from prior attempts to get your code working.

Comment: thing is it works perfectly before I added the isImportant attribute in my class and it shouldn't be nil since i'm saving stuff

Comment: yes i deleted it many times and did a clean build :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The superficial reason for the crash is here:

```
let taskArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(taskData as Data) as? [Task] 

tasks = taskArray!
```

You are force unwrapping the optional `taskArray`.  If `taskArray` is `nil` then your program crashes.

It is safer to use a conditional unwrap, or you can use the nil coalescing operator to provide a default.

```
if let taskArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(taskData as Data) as? [Task] {
    tasks = taskArray
} else {
    // Unable to load tasks - do something
}
```

or

```
let taskArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(taskData as Data) as? [Task]
tasks = taskArray ?? []
```

The real question, is why did the initialiser fail?  Why is `taskArray` nil?

The answer to that lies in this line:

```
let importantdecode = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "importantBool") as? Bool else {
        return nil
}
```

The key `importantBool` was used to encode a Bool, not an object.

As `isImportant` is a `Bool`, `aCoder.encode(isImportant, forKey: "importantBool")` is calling [`encode(_ value: Bool, forKey: String)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoder/1409236-encode).

It can be confusing.  Since Swift knows the type of the value you are encoding it can call the correct `encode`.  When you are decoding it doesn't know the type that is associated with the key. You are responsible for calling the correct `decode...` function.

You want

```
guard let taskDate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "taskDate") as? String ,
    let task = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "task") as? String else {
        return nil
}
let importantDecode = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "importantBool")
self.init(task: task, taskDate: taskDate , isImportant:importantdecode)
```

Note that unlike `decodeObject`, `decodeBool` does not return an optional, so it cannot be part of the `guard` statement.

You should still code defensively and not force unwrap `taskArray`.

Comment: Thank you for such explanation the code worked marvelously, appreciate it!